# IE 8 Doc Mode - Pros and Cons of <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, meta-tags

What are the pros and cons of adding

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

to a website.  I would like IE 8 to render in the IE 8 Doc mode so styles are more cohesive across browsers.  I am just worried about negative consequences of adding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 will render in IE8 standards mode if you provide an appropriate DOCTYPE, like `<!DOCTYPE html>`. `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">` is unneeded to force it in this case.

The only consequence of adding it though would be that the soon to be released IE9 will render the page in IE8 compatibility mode. But if you really really wanted to add it for some reason, and still keep IE9 in its own standards mode you can work around it with a conditional comment

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
<![endif]-->
```

I just really don't see a point to adding it though. Just have `<!DOCTYPE html>` that will ensure standards mode in ALL browsers (including even IE6).

Comment: Actually, this is not correct.  Setting the just the doctype as you said and leaving the rest I have a site that says "Doc Mode: IE7 Standards" and "Browser Mode: IE8 Compat View" in IE8 developer tools.  This site is on a .edu domain.  But while on local host the doc and browser mode do render IE8 as you mention.